# Direction of magnetic field in cathode ray tube experiment

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons

[image]

In the diagram above, the S pole is pointing towards the cathode ray tube, and the magnetic field is coming out of the page causing the cathode rays to deflect upwards.

My question is, if it wasn't shown that the cathode rays deflect upwards, are we still supposed to be able to figure out that the magnetic field comes out of the page?

For a diagram like this,

[image]

It is clear that the magnetic field is coming out of the page, but for the first diagram, I can't figure out whether the magnetic field is going in or out of the page if the cathode rays weren't there.

Answer (score 1):

the lines going out from the  south pol of a magnet have always the direction to the south pol. maybe you draw the field lines for a single bar Manet, to see it.